# is there any SAS code to run macro that have been write in a column of database?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

This is what i would like to achieve.

I want to be able to have a macro that let me group_by with one or more number of variable(s). It is more like an argument in the ellipsis variable

If we code in R it would be something like this.

```
example <- function(...) {
  vars1 <- syms(...) 
  df1 <- mtcars %>%
         group_by(!!!vars1) %>%
         summarise(Mean = mean(mpg))

  df2 <- mtcars %>%
          group_by(!!!vars1) %>%
          summarise(Median = median(hp))
}
```

I couldn't find a way that similar to above code in SAS. As much as I love using R, my current workplace use SAS. Therefore, need to find some workaround on this. Thus, I create a dataset with a bunch of macro to be called later on like below.

| Macro_Nm |
| --- |
| %macro grp_by_turnover; Rptmth,mia_grp,acctnpl,NewNPL_byClass,turnover1band,CustIDBand %mend grp_by; |
| %macro grp_by_turnover; Rptmth,mia_grp,acctnpl %mend grp_by; |

I tried to run macro code that available in a set of data that contains a bunch of macro to be run in sas.  Let say the data named ref. Following is the code that I have tried.

```
%macro ExtractACell(DThave,rownum, VarName, Name);
    data _null_;
        set &DThave.(obs=&rownum. firstobs=&rownum. keep = &VarName.);  
        call symputx(&Name., &VarName., "G");
        stop;
    run;
%mend ExtractACell;

data _null_;
%ExtractACell(ref, 11, F, "F"); 
%put &F;
call execute(&F);
run;
```

ERROR: Open code statement recursion detected.
ERROR: Macro keyword MEND appears as text.
WARNING: Extraneous text on %MEND statement ignored for macro definition GRP_BY_TURNOVER.
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have code as data and you want to run it the easiest way is to write the code into a file and %INCLUDE the file.

```
%macro ExtractACell(DThave,rownum, VarName);
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set &DThave.(obs=&rownum. firstobs=&rownum. keep = &VarName.);  
  file code ;
  put &varname;
run;
%include code ;
filename code ;
%mend ExtractACell;

%ExtractACell(DThave=ref,rownum=11, VarName=f)
```

It does not matter if the code is a macro definition or just normal SAS code. But note that just running a %MACRO definition will not actually execute the macro, just define it.

You could also use CALL EXECUTE() (especially if all the code does is define a macro since then there are no timing issues to worry about).  Since a variable can only hold 32,767 bytes you probably will want to add an lastobs or numobs option to the macro so that you could store longer code in the dataset.  But at this point you might as well not define a macro as just writing the datastep is barely any longer or complex than calling the macro.

```
data _null_;
  set ref(firstobs=11 obs=12);  
  call execute(f);
run;
```

Comment: Yes.. i would like to run %macro definition so that it can be call later on. Thanks for the help. For filename code temp , do i have to change to any variable name/ file name or anything?

Comment: Just don't use a fileref that you are using for something else.  So if you are already using CODE to refer to some other file use a different name.  You could probably use CALL EXECUTE() instead of writing to a file, especially if all the code does is define a macro.  Note that a variable in dataset is limited to 32,767 bytes.  So you can only define short macros in one observation of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.
Your code is mixing scopes and steps.  The data _null_ cannot nest another data _null_.  Your data is defining a macro and resolution of a data cell, in the correct scope, will compile the macro.  It will **not** also invoke the compiled macro (unless the data is doing so as well).  You data cells might not need to be macro definitions, but rather simply code snippets that can be injected into the supervisor stream once you communicate a better explanation of expected scope context.

You might need to look into OPEN/FETCHOBS/CLOSE to dynamically obtain a data cell value without causing a step boundary to be crossed.  You might do such in macro scope via %sysfunc.

Example

This example is fraught with potential problems due to uncontrolled nature of evaluating code snippets delivered via data.

```
%macro inject(data=,var=,obs=);
  %local dsid rc cell varnum;
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&data(keep=&var)));
  %let varnum = %sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,&var));
  %let rc = %sysfunc(fetchobs(&dsid,&obs));
  %let cell = %qsysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,&varnum));
&cell
  %let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
%mend;

/* a 'paint-by-numbers' program from a palette of snippets */
%inject(data=ref,  var=f, obs=11)  /* no semicolon is correct */
%inject(data=ref2, var=g, obs=1)   
%inject(data=ref,  var=s, obs=125) 
%inject(data=ref3, var=p, obs=7)
```